# Is this specific case a two-edge-connected graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am doing some training, there is a test case I can not pass, I think it is a false case for two-edge-connected Graphy, but the answer says it is true

```
  "adjacentlists": [
    [1, 2, 3, 5],
    [0, 2],
    [0, 1],
    [0, 4, 5],
    [3, 5],
    [3, 4, 0]
  ]
```

if I remove edges[0], the graph will be split into 2 parts 1-2 and 3-4-5. So it is not two - edge - connected

By definition: a graph is connected if for every one of its edges, the edge's removal from the graph does not cause the graph to be disconnected. If removal of any single edge disconnects the graph, then it is not a two-edge-connected.

A graph is connected if, for every pair of vertices in the graph, there is a path of one or more edges connecting the given vertices. A graph that isn't connected is said to be disconnected.

Any thought helps!

Comment: If you have code that fails the test, you need to show the code.

Comment: Those aren't edges, they are adjacency lists.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Thanks for your comment first. This is more about a concept issue at this moment, is the case above 2-edges-connected graph? My code passed 11 test case and failed this case, I am trying to see my understanding about 2-edge-graph is correct

Comment: @user3386109  Thanks for your comment, I correct my post. So based on the adjacent list, is this a 2-edge-connected graph?

Comment: Yes, it's 2-edge-connected. The picture in RaffleBuffle's answer shows what the graph looks like.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, based on your adjacency list it's [2-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-edge-connected_graph). No single edge can be removed that will cause the graph to become unconnected.

[image]

Comment: Got it! Now understand it better. I was thinking the definition is about removing node, it is actually just about removing edge! I was thinking removing 0 will cause it disconnected, but we are talking about removing edges here. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Correct, this is not a [2-vertex-connected graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph).